# How can I get the color at a specific coordinate in a pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, colors, coordinates

How can I get the color at a specific coordinate in a pdf file.? Also, I do not know the coordinates. I have only a pdf file. I need to find out a coordinate and its color. I work in java and "`com.lowagie.text.pdf`" package. Please help me.

Comment: how do you want to get the color of a coordinate if u don't even know the coordinate? With which criteria do u wanna find out the coordinate?

Comment: @Soren : you are right. But whatever may be the coordinate I want to get the color. for testing a feasible coordinate can be selected.

Comment: Do u know the page u want the coordinate and its color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what I was looking for.

The code is here

**[Export PDF pages to a series of images in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550129/export-pdf-pages-to-a-series-of-images-in-java)**

Answer (score 2):

If you know the page then take the image of the page:

PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, pageNum); // get the page of the PDF
Image img = Image.getInstance(page); // wrap it in an image object

From there on convert the Image to a byte array and get your color at your coordinate.