# Output PDF using ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, pdf, web

I just want to ask if there is anyway to output PDFs in a webpage using the ServletOutputStream? For example I want to make the PDF still show if there is not Adobe plugin installed or Chrome is not used.

Answer (score 1):

The user will **have** to have some type of PDF viewer installed on their PC to open/read the PDF file, whether it is Adobe Reader or something else. You can send the user a PDF file for either opening in the browser or download (Save as attachment) simply by sending the correct HTTP headers. Specifically:

```
Content-type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=downloaded.pdf
Content-Length: XXX
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

The `Content-Disposition` header is the one that suggests a download vs "open in browser". Once you 
 have sent the headers, send a blank line and then write out your data (often base64 encoded).

Comment: Again, the requirement is "No plugins installed/Use only native Java sdks/no applets/no jsf".

Comment: Ok well you can probably use Java to read the PDF file and generic static image files from the file, which can definitely be viewed in the browser without plugins.

Comment: See this post for ideas/pointers on how to accomplish that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550129/export-pdf-pages-to-a-series-of-images-in-java .

Comment: Sure I could do that but the problem is the navigation for each image plus where the images would be stored once processed, I was given a red light when I suggested Applets and JSF. Thanks for the valiant attempt dude! ^^

Comment: What navigation? Save the images you create on your server (Output via Java FileOutputStream) and then put them in your HTML document one after another: `<img src="pdf_pg1.png" /> <img src="pdf_pg2.png" /> etc. Add some links to multiple HTML pages if there are too many images to display on one page. Not difficult!

Comment: Navigating through the PDF. If it's not too difficult then I guess that could be a solution! Thanks, I'd give you my best answer award but I already gave it. I hope a simple "Thank You" would be enough, good sir. :)

Comment: Sure, glad I could help. Perhaps you could at least "upvote". In the future consider waiting longer for other possible responses. You never know who/what might come along.

Comment: Sure good sir! Once I get 15 rep I will, this page is bookmarked.

Comment: FYI you can just uncheck the existing green check and change it. It gives us both rep points.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet can output any type of document it wants; however, the browser will only display documents that it knows how to, either natively (e.g. HTML, text, GIF, PNG, JPG, etc.) or via a plugin (PDF, SWF, etc).

If your servlet outputs a valid PDF document and the browser can't display it natively (like Chrome can) or can't load a plugin to render it (like Adobe) then it will probably ask the user to save it or choose a program which might be able to display it.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I should give up now. :)

Comment: Don't give up!  Just figure out what is possible and what is not and go from there!

Comment: But the requirement is "No plugins installed/Use only native Java sdks/no applets/no jsf".

Comment: Err, I was speaking generally.  If you're being asked to do something impossible then explain to your employer why the requirements are impossible and offer workarounds.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was thinking too, it was impossible. The boss finally gave up. Thanks for the support, and your idea isn't wasted, I learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 0):

+1 because is a valid question.

Client Side

You can use [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) a javascript library from mozilla to display pdfs as images

Server Side

If your pdf is on the File System [modified from here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-serve-up-a-pdf-from-a-servlet.html)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String pdfFileName = "pdf-test.pdf";
    String contextPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
    File pdfFile = new File(contextPath + pdfFileName);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + pdfFileName)
    response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
    }
}
```

If you are generating pdf in memory using libraries like [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int marginTop = 30;
    String title = "HELLO WORLD";

    final PDFont fontData = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    final int fontSize = 8;

    //java8 color issue
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");

    final PDPage page = new PDPage();
    final PDFont fontLabel = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
    final int titleFontSize = 12;
    float heightLabelText = fontLabel.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize;

    try (final PDDocument pdf = new PDDocument())
    {
        pdf.addPage(page);
        try (PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(pdf, page)) {
            float top = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - marginTop;

            float titleWidth = fontLabel.getStringWidth(title) / 1000 * titleFontSize;

            stream.setFont(fontLabel, titleFontSize);
            stream.beginText();
            stream.newLineAtOffset((page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - titleWidth) / 2, top - 25);
            stream.showText(title);
            stream.endText();
        }
        try(ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            pdf.save(output);
            resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
            resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"yourFile" + "-" + new Random().nextInt() + ".pdf" + "\"");
            byte[] bytes = output.toByteArray();
            resp.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
            resp.setContentLength((int) bytes.length);
        }

    }
}
```