# How to convert buffered image to image and vice-versa?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

Actually i am working on a image editing software and now i want to convert the buffered-image i.e :

```
  BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
```

to Image i.e in the format something like :

```
  Image image  = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
```

Is it possible to so?? If yes, then how??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

BufferedImage *is a(n)* Image, so the implicit cast that you're doing in the second line is able to be compiled directly.  If you knew an Image was really a BufferedImage, you would have to cast it explicitly like so:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;
```

Because BufferedImage extends Image, it can fit in an Image container.  However, any Image can fit there, including ones that are not a BufferedImage, and as such you may get a ClassCastException at runtime if the type does not match, because a BufferedImage cannot hold any other type unless it extends BufferedImage.

Comment: Actually i am trying to rotate my image, i can do it by using a image in form of : Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(file)); but i don noe how to do it when bufferd-image is given??

Comment: Saying "Image" to a BufferedImage is like calling a Cat an Animal - just because it's a Cat doesn't make it not an animal.  A BufferedImage is an Image but it's not any other type of Image - anything that takes an Image, generally speaking, can work with a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 11):

Example: say you have an 'image' you want to scale you will need a bufferedImage probably, and probably will be starting out with just 'Image' object. So this works I think... The AVATAR_SIZE is the target width we want our image to be:

```
Image imgData = image.getScaledInstance(Constants.AVATAR_SIZE, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);     

BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imgData.getWidth(null), imgData.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

bufferedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(imgData, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 8):

[BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) is a subclass of [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html). You don't need to do any conversion.

Comment: Actually i am trying to rotate my image, i can do it by using a image in form of : Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(file)); but i don noe how to do it when bufferd-image is given??

Answer (score 7):

You can try [saving (or writing) the Buffered Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) with the changes you made and then opening it as an Image.

**EDIT:**

```
try {
    // Retrieve Image
    BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(new File("old.png"));;
    // Here you can rotate your image as you want (making your magic)
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(buffer, "png", outputfile); // Write the Buffered Image into an output file
    Image image  = ImageIO.read(new File("saved.png")); // Opening again as an Image
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand.. I am not getting u... :(

Answer (score 5):

Just an information: let us all remember that the `Image` class is actually an abstract class and referencing a variable of this with a BufferedImage only stores or returns any Object's memory adress.

Also, wherefore, static `java.awt.image.imageIO`'s `read()` method returns a `BufferedImage` object, therefore no doubt that using operator/expression `instanceof BufferedImage` on that object will return `true`.

In fact, being abstract, `Image` class has such method signatures as:

1. `public abstract Graphics getGraphics()`
2. `public abstract ImageProducer getSource()`

among others.

I emphasize, an actual `Image` variable only holds memory adress of a concrete Image-subclass object, almost like pointers in C, C++, Ada, etc.

If you're introduced or advanced in those languages, and also of Java interface instances like `Runnable`, `javax.sound.Clip`, AWT's `Shape`, etc.. . Take note that `Image` has: `public abstract Image getScaledInstance(...)` - you get the point. (Of course, scaling in 2D Graphics programming is interchangeable to resizing, for which precision is desirable).

But in an impossible case when herein ImageIO method return `! (instanceof BufferedImage)` just create a new `BufferedImage` object with this `ImgObjNotInstncfBufImg` apassed to one of its constructor argument. Then, at (rational) will manipulate this in the logic of your code.

Anyways, the Affine Transform class is appropriate for transforming Shapes and Images to thier scaled, rotated, relocated, etc forms, so I recommend you to study about using an "affine transform".

Take note that you can manipulate the actual pixels in such Image's Raster - well another technical 2D Graphics jargon which must be referenced from a technical glossary - which perhaps a excercised skill in Java ways of binary blitwise operations will be needed, in types of Image buffers that store individual color attributes in a compact in of 32-bytes - 7-bits each for the alpha and RGB values.

I suspect your gonna use it in layering images. So, FINALLY, the rational is that you only reference `BufferedImage` with the abstract Image, and if ever your `Image` object isn't a `BufferedImage` one yet, then you can just make an image out of this related-but-non-BufferedImage-instance without having to worry about any conversion, casting, autoboxing or whatever; manipulating a BufferedImage really means manipulating also the underlying root Image data-bearing object that it points to.

Okay, finished; I think I certainly extracted and splintered out what deadlock you may have thought you are facing to. As I have said abstract classes in java, and also interfaces, are very much the equivaleng of the low-level, more-close-to-hardware operators called pointers in other languages.

Comment: I honestly lost you few times there. It feels like this paragraphe of yours: "But in an impossible case when herein ImageIO method return ! (instanceof BufferedImage) just create a new BufferedImage object with this ImgObjNotInstncfBufImg apassed to one of its constructor argument. Then, at (rational) will manipulate this in the logic of your code." has the hole answer, but I don't quite understand it. You've explained a lot, but went quite quick over the actual answer...

Answer (score 5):

The right way is to use `SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage,null)` to convert a BufferedImage to a JavaFX Image instance and `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image,null)` for the inverse operation.

Optionally the second parameter can be a WritableImage to avoid further object allocation.

Comment: The question is old and predates JavaFX 2, so it would have been referring to a [`java.awt.Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) and not a [`java.scene.image.Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html).  However, this answer is still useful because if somebody comes across the question and really wants to convert a BufferedImage to a JavaFX image, this is indeed the way to do it.

Comment: My bad, I was just wondering, because all solutions write to the disk which is undesirable in terms of performance.