# Java converting Image to BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, casting, bufferedimage

There is already question like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132149/how-to-convert-buffered-image-to-image-and-vice-versa) on StackOverflow and the accepted answer is "casting":

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;
```

In my program I try:

```
final float FACTOR  = 4f;
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("graphic.png"));
int scaleX = (int) (img.getWidth() * FACTOR);
int scaleY = (int) (img.getHeight() * FACTOR);
Image image = img.getScaledInstance(scaleX, scaleY, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;
```

Unfortunatelly I get run time error:

> sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Obviously casting does not work.
Question is: What is (or is there) the proper way of converting Image to BufferedImage?

Comment: if you want to scale buffered image,

try this
try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage

Comment: For the record, it is NOT the compiler that is saying that.  You are actually seeing a runtime error ... not a compilation error.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for pointing this out. I will edit question accordingly.

Comment: @user902383 Even if they are not answering my question directly - those are great solutions as well.

Comment: Small Thing to OP: Method `ImageIO.read(File)` returns a `BufferedImage` by its signature.  ([Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29))  There is no need to first assign to an `Image` variable then cast to type `BufferedImage`.  That might confuse people reading your code.

Comment: @kevinarpe - I thought it is quite clear that the part of code you mention is not actual mine. I wrote in the question - this is "accepted answer" from a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132149/how-to-convert-buffered-image-to-image-and-vice-versa) on SO.

Comment: Why do you first create an `Image` object, and then cast it to a `BufferedImage`, when you have the option to create a `BufferedImage` from the beginning?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

From a [Java Game Engine](http://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/util/ImageTool.java#31):

```
/**
 * Converts a given Image into a BufferedImage
 *
 * @param img The Image to be converted
 * @return The converted BufferedImage
 */
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img)
{
    if (img instanceof BufferedImage)
    {
        return (BufferedImage) img;
    }

    // Create a buffered image with transparency
    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Draw the image on to the buffered image
    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    // Return the buffered image
    return bimage;
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to copy the whole image memory?

Comment: @TomášZato I think that's the only way to convert from an `Image` to a `BufferedImage`. You shouldn't be worrying about the memory when using Java.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati `You shouldn't be worrying about the memory when using Java.` Judging from average memory consumption by Java applications, other developers definitely don't worry about memory a little bit.

Comment: @TomášZato It seemed to me that you were from the C++ world, thinking to reuse the memory of the pixels of the image data. I mean by my previous comment that there is no need to worry about the memory in this case, as the GC will take care of it in Java.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati So garbage collectors don't consume any resources? GC only saves you from the *code* surrounding memory. It doesn't eradicate a hardware limit.

Comment: This won't work if `Image` is not loaded yet, since `getWidth(null)` or `getHeight(null)` will return `-1` in the case

Comment: @Dims Yup true, but in order to convert, one must load the file.

Comment: I had to use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` instead of ARGB to get the colours of my thumbnail right

Comment: A simple example is created here 'https://github.com/satyarajp/ImageManager/tree/main/resize/src/main/java/com/dynimg/resize/controllers' for more clarity. Thanks @Stephani I also faced the same issue.

Answer (score 22):

One way to handle this is to create a new BufferedImage, and tell it's graphics object to draw your scaled image into the new BufferedImage:

```
final float FACTOR  = 4f;
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("graphic.png"));
int scaleX = (int) (img.getWidth() * FACTOR);
int scaleY = (int) (img.getHeight() * FACTOR);
Image image = img.getScaledInstance(scaleX, scaleY, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(scaleX, scaleY, TYPE);
buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0 , null);
```

That should do the trick without casting.

Comment: Don't ever forget to dispose created graphics instances

Comment: How to "dispose created graphics interfaces"?

Comment: Should the type in the BufferedImage constructor match the one in the getScaledInstance?

Comment: No, the TYPE is something like ARGB or RGBA, the way the image data is stored internally - choose what feels most naturally to your application ; Just look into your Autocomplete when typing BufferedImage.[Autocomplete] to see all choices

Answer (score 4):

If you use Kotlin, you can add an extension method to Image in the same manner Sri Harsha Chilakapati suggests.

```
fun Image.toBufferedImage(): BufferedImage {
    if (this is BufferedImage) {
        return this
    }
    val bufferedImage = BufferedImage(this.getWidth(null), this.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)

    val graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics()
    graphics2D.drawImage(this, 0, 0, null)
    graphics2D.dispose()

    return bufferedImage
}
```

And use it like this:

```
myImage.toBufferedImage()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting back a `sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage`, you can cast the Image to that, and then use [getBufferedImage()](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/awt/image/ToolkitImage.html#getBufferedImage%28%29) to get the `BufferedImage`.

So instead of your last line of code where you are casting you would just do:

```
BufferedImage buffered = ((ToolkitImage) image).getBufferedImage();
```

Comment: 1) It is frowned upon to use classes from the `sun` package.  They are not guaranteed to be available in non-Oracle JDKs.  2) Method `getBufferedImage()` only works if the buffered image has been generated internally by `TookitImage`.  Most often (99%) it is not, so the return value is `null`.  [Source Reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/awt/image/ToolkitImage.java#ToolkitImage.getBufferedImage%28%29)