# How to convert Image to BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

How to convert [`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) to [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) in Java?

Note, that [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13605411/258483) is apparently not correct, because it uses methods [`getWidth(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getWidth-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) and [`getHeight(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getHeight-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-), which can return `-1` if image is not loaded yet (`Image` is, by definition, an asynchronous object).

Please, provide either more correct answer, or more proofs that existing answer is already correct.

Comment: You need to create an empty BufferedImage to copy the pixels to. Therefore you will need the dimensions of the original image.

Comment: I can't know the dimensions of original image until it's loaded.

Comment: o gosh I tried converting two images to bufferedImages 
and I was getting really close to a tantrum cause I did not understand why one 
would convert and the other not :) I had to load both before as setIcon and setRolloverIcon to my JButton before altering, that did the trick
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's important to you, you can use a `MediaTracker` to "wait" for the image to be loaded, then you don't need to care about supplying a `ImageObserver`

```
try {
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(new JPanel());
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("...");
    mt.addImage(image, 0);
    System.out.println("Wait for...");
    mt.waitForAll();
    System.out.println("I be loaded");

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Have a look at [`MediaTracker` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Image.html) for more details

> I don't wish to add any GUI, I just need to download image or fail

Okay, if you "need to download" the image, then you can just use `ImageIO.read(URL)`, have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details ... then you won't need to care about `Image` or `MediaTracker`, as `ImageIO` returns a `BufferedImage`

Comment: What is the purpose of `Component` in `MediaTracker`'s constructor? I don't wish to add any GUI, I just need to download image or fail

Comment: The `Component` is acting as the `ImageObserver` for the `MediaTracker`.  Okay, if you "need to download" the image, then you can just use `ImageIO.read(URL)`, have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details ... then you won't need to care about `Image` or `MediaTracker`, as `ImageIO` returns a `BufferedImage`

Comment: I don't have URL, I have an image in `Image` instance form

Comment: Then you need the `MediaTracker`, the creation of the `Component` won't "start" any UI, it's just using it to facilitate the `ImageObserver` API reqiurements