# Unable to call getWidth() on an Image

Tags: java

I have an Image `displayStartText` and `originalStartText` initialized thusly:

```
Image originalStartText = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "GAME/resources/ready_set_fight.gif" )).getImage();
Image displayStartText = originalStartText;
```

I try to draw displayStartText centered in my background with:

```
g2d.drawImage( displayStartText, (int)((bgDispWidth-displayStartText.getWidth())/2), (int)((bgDispHeight-displayStartText.getHeight())/2), null );
```

But a compiler error that I don't understand shows up

```
Gameplay.java:694: error: method getWidth in class Image cannot be applied to given types;
     g2d.drawImage( displayStartText, (int)((bgDispWidth-displayStartText.getWidth())/2), (int)((bgDispHeight-displayStartText.getHeight())/2), null );
                                                                         ^
  required: ImageObserver
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Any insights on why I might run into this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` doesn't have a `getWidth()` method, if you look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getWidth-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) you will find that it requires a parameter of `ImageObserver`, because the image might not be loaded when you request the value (because of the way it works), you can use an `ImageObserver` to be notified when data becomes available.

All Swing components implement `ImageObserver`, so you could (in theory) use `this` if the class was Swing based object or `null` if you don't have one.

If you're using `null`, then you should ensure that the image is loaded first, using `MediaTracker` for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714751/how-to-convert-image-to-bufferedimage-in-java/32715012#32715012), otherwise `getWidth(ImageObsever)` may return `-1`

A better solution (IMHO) would be to use `ImageIO.read` which will return a `BufferedImage` which is gurenteed to be loaded when it returns and saves you some of these problems.

Have a look at [Reading/Loading an image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: A caveat: I tried using ImageIO.read and BufferedImage at first, but it caused my animated GIFs to no longer animate.

Comment: Yep, that will happen :P

Comment: @hj Sorry, I was thinking of something else :P, basically, `ImageIcon` is the preferred method for this, in which case, you'll need to either us an `ImageObserver` or pass it `null`, but check the caveat for using `null`

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and see what comes up

Comment: I got it to work. I just passed getWidth and getHeight with null arguments. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just beware it can return `-1` if the image isn't fully loaded ;)