# Compress List<Image> in a Zip

Tags: java, image, zip, javax.imageio

I am tring to compress a list of Images into a single zip file.

```
public void compressZip(List<Image> lstImage) {
    //Abrimos una ventana JFileChooser
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int seleccion = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(laminaComicPrincipal);
    if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
       File fichero = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
       try {
            ZipOutputStream os = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichero.getAbsolutePath()+"file.zip"));
            int numeroImagen = 0;
            for(Image imagen: lstImage){

                ZipEntry entrada = new ZipEntry(numeroImagen+".jpg");
                os.putNextEntry(entrada);

                ImageInputStream fis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(imagen);//THis sentences return null
                byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int leido=0;
                while (0 < (leido=fis.read(buffer))){   //FAIL SENTENCES --> fis=null
                   os.write(buffer,0,leido);
                }

                fis.close();
                os.closeEntry();
                numeroImagen++;
            }
            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

`ImageIO.createImageInputStream(image n)` returns `null`. What's the problem?? If I save the Images in HDD first, and use `FileInputStream` to read the files, will it work? but I prefer not to create temporally files.

Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageInputStream-java.lang.Object-) you will find your answers

> Returns an ImageInputStream that will take its input from the given Object. The set of ImageInputStreamSpis registered with the IIORegistry class is queried and the first one that is able to take input from the supplied object is used to create the returned ImageInputStream. **If no suitable ImageInputStreamSpi exists, null is returned.**

And

> input - an Object to be used as an input source, **such as a File, readable RandomAccessFile, or InputStream**.

(Emphasis added by me)

So basically, the method is expecting a `File` or `InputStream`, not an `Image`. If you convert your `Image` to `RenderedImage` (ie a `BufferedImage`), then you can just use `ImageIO.write` to write the image directly to the `ZipOutputStream`

Then your question becomes [How to convert Image to BufferedImage in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714751/how-to-convert-image-to-bufferedimage-in-java/32715012#32715012)