# Convert java.awt.Image object to byte array (`byte[]`)

Tags: java, arrays, image, javax.imageio

If I have a [`java.awt.Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,int,int)) object in hand, how can I get a byte array of the image data?

---

If I had the subclass [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) I could do this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
ImageIO.write( thumbnail , "jpeg" , baos ) ;
baos.flush();
final byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray() ;
```

…where [`ImageIO.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,java.lang.String,java.io.File)) takes an [`RenderedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html) — an interface implemented by `BufferedImage` but not implemented by its superclass `java.awt.Image`.

Unfortunately, I do not have a [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) or [`RenderedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html). After having called [`getScaledInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,int,int)) on my original [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) object to get a reduced [thumbnail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbnail) image, I have only a [`java.awt.Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,int,int)) object in hand. I am trying to get a byte array of the data in that [`java.awt.Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,int,int)) object.

Comment: Draw the image to a `BufferedImage` - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714751/how-to-convert-image-to-bufferedimage-in-java/32715012#32715012) ;)

Comment: Looks like a better way to go is to use a library such as [`imgscalr`](https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr) or [`java-image-scaling`](https://github.com/mortennobel/java-image-scaling) rather than the outmoded and troublesome `java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance` route I was using when I posted this Question.

Comment: For discussion about the problems with [`java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,int,int)), see [*The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance() Blog*](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611) posted 2007-2015 by [Chris Adamson](https://www.linkedin.com/in/invalidname/).

Comment: You don’t have to use getScaledInstance.  You can use a [draw method that scales](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,int,int,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29), or, when your source is a BufferedImage, you can use [RescaleOp](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html).

Comment: @VGR `RescaleOp` "scales" color sample values (making them lighter, darker etc), it does not change image dimensions. For that, use `AffineTransformOp`. Otherwise, good advice. I'd still use a library like imgscalr to get good quality thumbnails though... :-)

Comment: @haraldK Oops, you’re right, my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a new `BufferedImage` object, then get its graphics object by calling `.getGraphics()` on that, and then draw your image into it, using `.drawImage` on the graphics object, and then convert the BufferedImage to a PNG or JPG.