# How can I convert a BufferedImage to an Image?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I'm trying to split up an image of a deck of cards and store an individual card into an Image.

```
Image image;
BufferedImage deck = ImageIO.read( new URL( "http://www.jfitz.com/cards/classic-playing-cards.png" ) );
image = deck.getSubimage( x, y, width, height );
```

incompatible types: BufferedImage cannot be converted to Image

Everywhere I've looked says that BufferedImage *is* an Image, this problem shouldn't exist. (Note: if this comes off looking like a class assignment, it is, but all we're supposed to do is load an image from a predetermined directory. I'm trying to take it a step further by using the URL for fun.)

**EDIT 04/09/2014**
I've been using different imports, so I guess the question I'm really trying to ask is how to convert a java.awt.image.BufferedImage to a java.scene.image.Image. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Indeed, `BufferedImage` is a sub-class of `Image`.  What version of Java compiler are you using?  Are you sure you're importing the correct `Image` class?

Comment: Are you sure that `image` is of type `java.awt.image.Image` and isn't an `image` from some other package?

Comment: What `import` statement are you using at the top of your file?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this answer.

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9132226/1571550

Comment: All answers below seems to assume that you are referring to `java.awt.Image`, in which case any `BufferedImage` can be assigned to `image` (and the answers doesn't make much sense). The problem is most likely that you have the wrong import (like `javafx.scene.image.Image` or similar), or that you indeed want a different kind of `Image` (in that case, you have to tell us which one to receive any meaningful help).

Comment: Thanks, commenters. Yeah, that's the problem- I've been using javafx.scene.image.Image, I'll edit my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once I knew what question to ask, google answered this really quickly. I found a quick fix on this [blog](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/01/convert-javaawtimagebufferedimage-to.html).

```
BufferedImage tempCard = deck.getSubimage( x, y, width, height );
Image card = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(tempCard, null );
```

Tried it out and works great!

Answer (score 0):

[BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) is a subclass of [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html). **You don't need to do any conversion.**

You can just assign like:

```
Image image;
BufferedImage deck = ImageIO.read( new URL( "http://www.jfitz.com/cards/classic-playing-cards.png" ) );
image = deck;// That will do
```

Comment: I agree, it *should* just work. Except that the OP states that their compiler complains at this

Answer (score -1):

A BufferedImage extends Image which means that you can declare a BufferedImage like so:

```
Image myImage = ImageIO.read(new URL("my/url"));
```

This starts getting into polymorphism and inheritance.  Your object may be a BufferedImage, but a BufferedImage is still an Image and it can be used as one.

A more recognizable example perhaps would be instantiating an ArrayList as a List

```
List<MyType> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This allows this ArrayList to be compatible with all types of List objects, just like the BufferedImage.

Take a look at the [API page for Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html).

It lists all known subclasses of this abstract class, BufferedImage included.  (There's only 2.)

Answer (score -2):

```
Image image = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage).getImage();
```

That's the way I usually do it...
OR

```
Image image = (Image) bufferedImage;
```

Comment: There's no need to do anything. A `BufferedImage` *is an* `Image` (ie. `BufferedImage extends Image`).

Comment: As others have pointed out, that's not entirely true.  There are different Image classes (AWT, SWT, etc.).  BufferedImage extends AWT image, but not SWT image and there's no _easy_ way to go from BI to SWT image, which is the problem I am having (which brought me here).

Comment: `The method ImageIcon(BufferedImage) is undefined`.