# Barbecue library, barcode prob

Tags: java, graphics, barcode, barbecue

i have a small problem. I successfully generated a barcode using barbecue library but i'm trying to print on a paper of size 99x210 and unfortunately i can't resize the barcode. It's too big.

I'm generating like this

```
try {
    Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128("630798898");
    Image image = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 30,100, this );
} catch (OutputException | BarcodeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used something like this

```
    BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;
                    Scalr.resize(buffered,
                            Scalr.Method.SPEED,
                            Scalr.Mode.AUTOMATIC,
                            50,
                            5);
```

but its not doing job :/

I tried to set  height and width of whole barcode by using setBarHeight, setBarWidth, setResolution but it's working too.

Comment: Convert the `Image` to a `BufferedImage`, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605248/java-converting-image-to-bufferedimage) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132149/how-to-convert-buffered-image-to-image-and-vice-versa); scale the image, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: Why do it this way? Because the resulting quality of the image is better then simply using something like `Image#getScaledInstance`