# Extracting whole page as image iTextPdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Is it possible to extract pages from an existing pdf file and save the whole page as an image through iTextPDF  library.

for example if my pdf file contains 2 pages then 2 images will be generated and each image will be a snapshot of a particular page.

Comment: What do you mean by *image* here? A graphic?

Comment: iText cannot be used for *rendering* PDF files. So the answer is no, it's not possible.

Comment: Image equivalent to as if you are taking the print screen of the pdf page

Comment: @yms is there any other way of rendering PDF files ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export PDF pages to a series of images in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550129/export-pdf-pages-to-a-series-of-images-in-java)

Comment: Yes. You just need [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/550172/767881).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a page from pdf and save it to an image file with itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935204/get-a-page-from-pdf-and-save-it-to-an-image-file-with-itext)

Answer (score 0):

I used PDF-Renderer and jpedal api but the image resolution generated by these api was poor.

But I finally achieved this by [PDFBox API](http://pdfbox.apache.org). This api also has the ability to set the resolution of the image.