# How to render a Pdf page to an raster image by using iText 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

It is quite straghtforward to render as a bitmap any page of a PDF file by using Apache pdfbox.
But how to do it with iText?

Comment: AFAIK itext doesn't do rendering into raster images. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935204/get-a-page-from-pdf-and-save-it-to-an-image-file-with-itext?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ex-iText employee here.
This is currently not possible with `iText`.

If you'd look at the GitHub repositories of `iText`, you'd see that they also use an external tool `ImageMagick` to render PDF to image.

Comment: Is it possible yet?

Comment: No idea. I didn't keep up with `iText` after I quit. I moved on to other companies, started working in Python. Then I noticed there wasn't a great PDF library for Python. And I wrote one. I'm currently the author/ceo of `borb`.

Comment: Congrats.  We were using Python on a different project, but that library didn't handle pdf's with forms.  I hope yours does much better.