# How to convert bitmap to PNG and then to base64 in Android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, png, base64

As the title implies, I'm trying to get the user of my Android app to select an image from his device (done), I then want to scale the image down (done), compress/convert the image to png and send it to an API as a base64 string.

So I currently resize the image like so:

```
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION, MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

I then have a bitmap, which I want to convert to a PNG, and from there to a base64. I found some example code to convert to a PNG and store it on the device [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location).

```
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
       out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that I do not want to save the image. I just want to keep it in memory as a PNG and then convert it further to a base64 string.

Does anybody know how I could convert the image to a png and store it in a variable that way, or even better, convert it to base64 immediately? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this to convert bitmap into png:

```
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outStream);
```

Check [method's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

You can directly convert bitmap to Base64. Use this for encoding and decoding from and to Base64.

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
}
```

Comment: Where does outStream go?

Comment: I used `Base64.NO_WRAP` per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32935972/435605

Comment: Also, please remember to close streams. Though no really needed here, it's a good practice and prevents some warnings.