# Java: Different results when decoding base64 string with java.util.Base64 vs android.util.Base64

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm working on a client/server system and I'm trying to do some basic encryption. When I connect to the server, I send a public key as an escaped string across the socket. I've verified that the string is **identical** on both ends, newlines and all.

On the client (Android), I'm able to use the public/private keys to successfully encrypt and decrypt a secret key (for testing purposes). However, the server fails right out of the gate when trying to decode the public key from a String to a byte[], with:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a
```

which seems preposterous, as 'a' is absolutely a base64 character, if I understand correctly. The client and server use a shared library to handle all encryption, so the code is nearly identical. The *only* difference is encoding/decoding base64 Strings, since java.util.Base64 is unavailable on Android.

**Shared class**

```
public abstract class EasyCrypt {

...

    public PublicKey loadPublicKey(String key64) throws GeneralSecurityException {

        byte[] data = decode(key64); //Calls abstract methods, shown below

        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return fact.generatePublic(spec);
    }

...

}
```

**Client (Android) methods**

```
import android.util.Base64;

public class ClientCrypt extends EasyCrypt {
    @Override
    protected byte[] decode(String s) {
        return Base64.decode(s.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT); //Works perfectly
    }

    @Override
    protected String encode(byte[] bytes) {
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

}

**Server (Linux) methods**

```
import java.util.Base64;

public class ServerCrypt extends EasyCrypt{
    @Override
    public byte[] decode(String str){
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(str); //Throws IllegalArgumentException
    }

    @Override
    public String encode(byte[] bytes){
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    }
```

}

Comment: try using `Base64.NO_WRAP` instead of `DEFAULT` in android

Comment: Android is the one that's working correctly.

Comment: you are encoding it on android right ? if yes then try `Base64.NO_WRAP` in your encode method on android

Comment: Can you show base64str u r trying to decode?

Comment: I believe you have formatting issues, its either wrapped or tabbed in some fashion

Comment: @MohammadAdil wow, that was it! Sorry I doubted your first comment. That fixed the problem, so if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213780. `a` stands for `0x0A`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

On android, Use `Base64.NO_WRAP` instead of `Base64.DEFAULT`

```
@Override
protected String encode(byte[] bytes) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Comment: @Mohammad Adil i got a string from server encoded by java.util.Base64 class and i am decoding that string with android.util.base64 that not giving desired result. pls help me

Comment: Thanks for `Base64.NO_WRAP` it's working in my Java backend (using java.util.Base64).

Comment: want to do in java. i dont have android. by using java.util.Base64 result is different

Answer (score 13):

Instead of `Base64.getDecoder()` use `Base64.getMimeDecoder()`.

Comment: java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder() call requires API level 26.

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode) for further explanation.