# Android getBytes("ISO-8859-1") return wrong value

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a problem with encoded string. I have a string that returns from soap request in my android app. This string is crypted by AES with key and ivs. The problem is that char "à" is shown as "?". This is the code:

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
String xmlCryptResponse = response.toString();
String decrypt = AES64.decrypt(key, ivs, xmlCryptResponse );
```

and this is the class AES64:

```
public class AES64 {
public static String encrypt(String key, String ivs, String value) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivs.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),
                "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
        String r = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return r;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String key, String ivs, String encrypted) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivs.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),
                "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encrypted.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), Base64.DEFAULT));

        return new String(original);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return ex.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

I used the same string response in java console application and it works fine, the char "à" is recognized, tha class AES64 is similar, only difference is that in java application i use java.util.Base64 not android.util.Base64.
I don't understand why in android, ISO-8859-1 returs wrong char.
Can you help me please?? I spent a few days to resolve this problem but nothing.

PS: This is the start of the xml decrypted from the string response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

Thank you guys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935783/java-different-results-when-decoding-base64-string-with-java-util-base64-vs-and

Comment: I try it but doesn't work.