# Base64 does not encode the entire string

Tags: java, android, base64, encode

When I encode tex, for some reason it cuts off part of the string ... What could be the problem?

```
        DateFormat dateFormat =
                new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR,+ 9);
        String server_time = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        String wmsAuthSign = "server_time=" + server_time + "&hash_value=U2QK9TLB55JWTZr3OKZHtg==&validminutes=120";
        wmsAuthSign = "?wmsAuthSign=" + Base64.encodeToString(wmsAuthSign.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I am submitting something like this:

```
server_time=02/18/2019 23:38:43 PM&hash_value=U2QK9TLB55JWTZr3OKZHtg==&validminutes=120
```

And if you decode the encoded text, you get a trimmed result:

```
server_time=02/18/2019 23:38:43 PM&hash_value=U2QK9TLB55J
```

Comment: I tried the same byte [], the result is the same

Comment: What does the encoded string look like and how do you decode the Base64 String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [RFC-2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt):

> ```
> (5)   (Soft Line Breaks) The Quoted-Printable encoding
>       REQUIRES that encoded lines be no more than 76
>       characters long.  If longer lines are to be encoded
>       with the Quoted-Printable encoding, "soft" line breaks
> ```

source data string:

`server_time=02/18/2019 23:38:43 PM&hash_value=U2QK9TLB55JWTZr3OKZHtg==&validminutes=120`

Base64 encoded to string:

```
c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MDIvMTgvMjAxOSAyMzoxMjo1NiBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVUyUUs5VExCNTVK
V1RacjNPS1pIdGc9PSZ2YWxpZG1pbnV0ZXM9MTIw
```

exactly like it shown above: with line break. But on receiver side you probably decode only first line

`c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MDIvMTgvMjAxOSAyMzoxMjo1NiBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVUyUUs5VExCNTVK`

that is `server_time=02/18/2019 23:12:21 PM&hash_value=U2QK9TLB55J`

So decode on receiver side whole received data, not only first line.

Or you may be sent to receiver side only first line of encoded Base64.

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32935972/6950238) answer of [Mohammad Adil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235710/mohammad-adil):

> On android, Use `Base64.NO_WRAP` instead of `Base64.DEFAULT`

Comment: How come the base64 adds a line break?

Comment: @Nathan RFC 2045, which defined Base64, requires a newline after 76 characters. `c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MDIvMTgvMjAxOSAyMzoxMjo1NiBQTSZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPVUyUUs5VExCNTVK` is exactly 76 chars and decoded to `server_time=02/18/2019 23:38:43 PM&hash_value=U2QK9TLB55J`.

Comment: But then I wonder why the decoding function is not recognizing this line break.

Comment: Apparently the encoded value is not correctly URL encoded (as query parameter) so you not only loose the second line, but also the 'validminutes' parameter

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenkoOki, didn't know that. Maybe you could add this part to your answer, for people like me :p

Comment: Sincerely grateful.